# Jsplumb angular2 implmenetation

Tags: javascript, angular, jsplumb

I am having an issue with implmenting Jsplumb on angular2.

I am trying to layer jsplumb in angular2 with a component but I am getting an error saying **jsPlumb.ready is not a function**

I imported it throught npm and put it in my vendor.js for webpack

here is the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
var $ = require('jquery');
var jsPlumb = require('jsplumb');
@Component({
    selector: 'jsplumb-plot',
    template: require('./jsplumb.plot.component.html'),
    providers: []
})
export class JsplumbPlotComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        jsPlumb.ready(function () {
            console.log("this");
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the webpack import

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '', '.js' ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            ....
            'jsplumb/dist/css/jsplumbtoolkit-defaults.css',
            'jsplumb/dist/js/jsplumb.min.js'
        ]
    },
```

**Note that i see jsplumb's javascript code in my vendor.js after webpack compile. The issue is that I still cannot call from it.**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the proper way to import it was,

```
import { jsPlumb } from 'jsplumb';
```